# Impedir Barra de Rolagem na Navbar no Materializecss

Tags: rolamento, materialize, nav-bar

Estou usando o Materializecss em um projeto, até aqui tudo certo. Acontece que não estou conseguido fazer uma parada com a barra de rolagem.

Como faço para impedir a barra de rolagem subir, entrar, passar por cima do navbar? de modo que ela role somente a div content da TAB

[image: Imagem ilustrando meu problema: barra de rolagem por cima da navbar]

O que eu preciso é disso:
[image: rola da navbar para baixo]

Comment: Tenta colocar o header como fixo e na div content a regra css : overflow-y:scroll;

Comment: Vou tentar e posto o resultado